# Extracting data based on dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a Google sheet that is tracking all GED attendance (multiple classes and teachers). I am trying to pull out the student and class info by teacher so we can see a snapshot of that teachers class enrollments. I would like to have 1 sheet with a dropdown of the teacher names that shows only the students and class attendance for that selected teacher, but am having issues referencing the row that the teacher's name on the attendance sheet.

I tried using the indirect formula embedded in the Query formula and using the & around the row reference, but keep getting an error message. Here is a replica of the sheet I am working with (lists is dropdown named ranges) and I included an example of what I would like to pull.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UN_EvpF-f0Im-Y2V3qPG7RJAhotrEBtUXrFfzhCTnA8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Its quite complex to get working because you have so many merged cells. Merged cells are not read by the QUERY function, so it just ignores them. Are you able to somehow get by with text boxes or a different design instead of merged cells?

Answer (score 0):

#### Mind your quotation marks and brackets

Your actual formula is:

```
IFERROR(
    Query(
        GED!$A$1:$K$1002,
        "Select * where AZ$3 = ''&Teacher View!$B$1&''"),"")"))"
```

To modify this formula to get rid of your error:

```
=IFERROR(
    Query(
        GED!$A$1:$K$1002,
        "Select * where AZ$3 = "&'Teacher View'!$B$1),"")
```

- Double `"` or single `'` quotation marks need to be closed.
- The Concatenate symbol `&` should not be within quotation marks.
- You have 2 open brackets at the beginning of the equation, but 4 at the end. This will always give an error.
- `" Select * where AZ$3 = ''&Teacher View!$B$1&'' "` is just text, since it is all enclosed by double speech brackets.
- Note that if your sheet name has a space, you also need to enclose these in quotation marks.
- If you need literal quotation marks you can use `CHAR(34)`. Or you can enclose single quotation marks in double ones but not vice versa. `="'"` is ok, `='"'` will give you an error.

#### Is your formula on the right track?

I am not sure that formulas can be stretched so far as to produce the exact result you want.

- You have many merged cells. The `QUERY` function does not read these cells. Therefore you would need to previously use arrays to construct the range you want to QUERY. Something along these lines:

  ```
  ={GED!A7:AY7,GED!AZ3:GN3; GED!A8:GN300}
  ```

  Once you have your array, you could then in theory query or filter it, but it would require many intermediate steps, resulting in one of these types of formula:

  ```
  =QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(QUERY...
  ```

  Which are very hard to read, maintain or modify. I would personally start looking into [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) at this point.
- You could reorganize your main data sheet `GED` into another format that is more formula friendly. The first order of business here would be getting rid of the merged cells.

  Bear in mind that formulae work best when you have very tabular data. That is, one single row of headers and ideally your first column has a unique ID. If you can start with your data in this kind of format, it becomes much easier to create reports like what your `GED` sheet looks like now, and any other report or pivot table that you might like.

  This may not be possible or practical, and you need a solution that will read the format that is currently there, in which case, I would urge you to look into [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) as it will be far better in the long run.